# how to create a scoring system

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scoring

I'm trying to make my scoring system work. it keeps forgetting after I have changed the score once I go back into the class as it is set as 0. How would I change this so the score changes as appropriate?

code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class TimesTableGUI:
    
    def __init__(self, parent, score = 0):

        self.score = score
        
        #chooses a random number
        num1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num2 = random.randint(1,10)
        self.answer = num1 * num2

        #making labels
        entry_label = Label(parent, text = str(num1) + " * " + str(num2))
        entry_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.e1 = Entry(parent, width = 5)
        self.e1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        b1 = Button(parent, text = "Check Answer", command = self.check_answer)
        b1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        b2 = Button(parent, text = "Next", command = self.new_question)
        b2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.b1_output = Label(parent, text = self.score)
        self.b1_output.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    def check_answer(self): #callback for Check Answer button

        #check if users gets correct answer
        f = int(self.e1.get())
        if f == self.answer:
            self.score +=1
            self.b1_output.configure(text = self.score)
        else:
            self.b1_output.configure(text = self.score)

    def new_question(self): #callback for Next button to next question
        
        self.b1_output.configure(text = " ") 
        radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root) #restarts the class for new question
             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Task 3")
    radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This: `radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root) #restarts the class for new question` is a bad idea.

Comment: what would you recommend doing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import random
from tkinter import *

class TimesTableGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent, score=0):
        self.score = score
        self.master = parent
        self.ask_new_question()

        self.b1_output = Label(parent, text="Score = %i" % self.score)
        self.b1_output.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def ask_new_question(self):
        self.question_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.question_frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
        #chooses a random number
        num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
        num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.answer = num1 * num2

        #making labels
        entry_label = Label(self.question_frame, text="%i*%i" % (num1, num2))
        entry_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.e1 = Entry(self.question_frame, width=5)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.check_answer_btn = Button(self.question_frame, text="Check Answer",
                                       command=self.check_answer)
        self.check_answer_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        b2 = Button(self.question_frame, text="Next",
                    command=self.new_question)
        b2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def check_answer(self):
        user_answer = int(self.e1.get())
        if user_answer == self.answer:
            self.score += 1
            self.b1_output.configure(text="Score = %i" % self.score)
            # So the user can't submit more than 1 correct answer
            self.check_answer_btn.config(state="disabled")

    def new_question(self):
        # Remove the frame (and all of its children)
        self.question_frame.destroy()
        # Display the new question
        self.ask_new_question()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Task 3")
    radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I moved all of the widgets that are for the question inside a frame. The frame gets destroyed and recreated each time a new question needs to be displayed. I also made sure the user can't just keep clicking on `Check Answer` after they got the correct answer already (for that question).

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that when you you call `radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root)` score is getting reset too.
**Quick solution**: pass score when you call `radiobuttons = TimesTableGUI(root, score=self.score)` in `new_question`
**Better solution**: create a method that reset GUI without reinitialize the entire class.

Comment: This will keep creating new widgets on the screen without destroying the old ones.

Comment: This is exactly mentioned in the comments. Plus, your 'quick solution' will give a `NameError`.

Comment: I don't know honestly why you gave me a negativa evaluation. I said this was a quick solution not a good one, I put a better solution under that. Plus I tested it and didn't raise NameError. Plus Plus I don't see it in comments

Comment: It might not give an error when you run from the same file, but anyway, `self` wont be defined outside of classes. And this isnt a negative evaluation, its an honest evaluation.

Comment: I have no problem with a honest or a negative evaluation in general, I simply didn't understand the critique. Now I got it thank you!